# Duplicates in OneToMany annotated List

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, collections, one-to-many

I'm working on a Java project using JPA 2 + Hibernate 4.2.6 and I'm getting a strange behaviour.

In my model I have two related entites: `Question` and `Answer`

```
@Entity
public class Question {
    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Answer> answers;

    // ...
}


@Entity
public class Answer {
    // ...

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", nullable = false)
    private Question question;

    // ...
}
```

This works perfectly: all `Answer`s related to a certain `Question` are loaded correctly.

But now I need to change the tipe of `answers` collecton from `Set` to `List`. I changed the type and ran the application again and now I get several duplicates in `answers`...
Why is it possible? I know that `List` allows duplicates, but there are no duplicate records in my DB, so why I get these?

I read about some similar bugs in previous version of Hibernate, but I expect they are solved in last version... am I wrong?

**NOTE** I need to change `Set` into `List` because I need to keep information about the **order** for answers and, possibly, to change this order.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are most likely getting duplicates because when using fetch=FetchType.EAGER, Hibernate [uses an outer join](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association-fetching) to fetch the data in the joined table.

Try removing the eager fetching to confirm. If it is the case, you should either remove the eager fetching, keep a Set instead of a List, or write a JPQL query to retrieve exactly what you need.

From [Hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association-fetching):

> The recommanded approach is to use LAZY on all static fetching
>   definitions and override this choice dynamically through JP-QL.

Comment: You can also use @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT) with fetch=FetchType.EAGER. With this, no need to change from List to Set.

Comment: I was getting 38000 rows where it should  have been 38 only. That just killed my ECS instance. Using `Set` really saved me here. Didn't try @nimo23 's approach. How is it better than just replacing `List` with `Set`? How do these two approaches compare in term of efficiency?

Comment: @ParamvirSinghKarwal - 
If you use a Set you can't have an order (so first answer, second answer, etc).
From what I understand, FetchMode.SELECT less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I used Set after noticing it in @Paramvir Singh's comment.
It prevented the duplicates records

```
public class User  {
  
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Role> roles;
    
}
```